# Archive links don't work when clicked

Tags: archives

I have archive links in my theme that get the archives for a specfic category ('blog) like so:

```
 <?php wp_get_archives('cat=6'); ?>
```

When i click on the link for the archives is just loads the category page again for the blog.

The url does change to:

```
http://localhost:8888/2012/11/?cat=6
```

But nothing changes on the page.

Comment: That is an odd mix of pretty permalinks and default (straight PHP) permalinks. What setting do you have in wp-admin->Settings->Permalinks?

Comment: /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Which field? "Custom Structure"? Does other URL rewriting work? What is the server (Apache, IIS, etc.) what is the OS of the server?

Comment: custom structure, server is apache and linux. On my category page I have it split with if statements to show the posts different depending if its in the blog section or work section. I wonder if this has something to do with it. But i cannot find where the archive code is.

Answer (score 1):

OK. [Here is your problem.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

```
wp_get_archives( $args );
...
$args = array(
    'type'            => 'monthly',
    'limit'           => ,
    'format'          => 'html', 
    'before'          => ,
    'after'           => ,
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo'            => 1
);
```

You are use `wp_get_archives` incorrectly. That function accepts particular 'keys', and `cat` isn't one of them. You can use an array as above or the weird get-like string that is common in WordPress. You can't pass it values it isn't meant to handle though.

What you are seeing is the function fall back to its 'monthly' archive default, and apparently append your string to the end, which I wouldn't have expected.

Use [get_category_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) instead.

Comment: Ok, This has now started to work. But, how would I get archives from a certain cat?

Comment: Use `get_category_link`; see my answer.

Comment: Ok, but how can i filter these monthly?

Comment: I don't know of a function that will do that. Of course you can start filtering WP_Query

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is, when I click 'October'. How do i see all the posts from October? right now i just see one post, I need to see each post.

Comment: [This stuff is in the Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link#Month_Archive_as_Link) Also, that is very different from the OP.

Comment: sorry, what is OP?

Comment: Opening Post ... I am getting a warning about extended discussions, so ...